# How to avoid empty lists to be appended & parentheses and brackets

Tags: string, python-2.7, list

I am currently struggling with a small piece which should screen a large file and write out only specific data fulfilling certain restrictions giving by a a function. I have mainly formatting issues:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import numpy as np

log = open("out_test", "w")
log1 = open("out_test_empty", "w")

def function(kx,ky,ek,sz,ef,tol):
    lines = []
    if ((ef-tol)<ek<(ef+tol)):
        lines.append((kx,ky,sz))
#       (lines.append((kx,ky,sz)) if (kx,ky,sz) is not None else None)
    return lines


arr = []
with open('test10') as my_file:
    for line in my_file:
        ##numbers_float=map(float, line.split())
        arr.append(map(float, line.split()))
        print(function(arr[-1][0],arr[-1][1],arr[-1][2],arr[-1][3],-0.5462,0.001), file = log)
#       print(', '.join(str(d) for d in function(arr[-1][0],arr[-1][1],arr[-1][2],arr[-1][3],-0.5462,0.001)), file = log)
#       str_list = (', '.join(str(d) for d in function(arr[-1][0],arr[-1][1],arr[-1][2],arr[-1][3],-0.7,0.001)))
#       str_list = filter(None, str_list)
#       print(str_list, file =log)

#print(arr[:][:])

#import fileinput
#for line in fileinput.FileInput("test",inplace=1):
#    if line.rstrip():
#        print(line, file=log1)
```

The test data file (will be around 10^7 lines):

```
  0.11361097E+01  0.19677992E+01 -0.54626220E+00 -0.87053581E+00
  0.11361097E+01  0.19677992E+01 -0.54626220E+00  0.87053581E+00
  0.11361097E+01  0.19677992E+01  0.22336976E+01  0.90485914E+00
  0.11361097E+01  0.19677992E+01  0.22336976E+01 -0.90485916E+00
  0.11361097E+01  0.19677992E+01  0.23120941E+01 -0.42934308E+00
  0.11361097E+01  0.19677992E+01  0.23120941E+01  0.42934308E+00
  0.11361097E+01  0.19677992E+01  0.24740033E+01 -0.98827766E+00
  0.11361097E+01  0.19677992E+01  0.24740033E+01  0.98827766E+00
  0.11361097E+01  0.19677992E+01  0.24777489E+01 -0.52602145E+00
  0.11361097E+01  0.19677992E+01  0.24777489E+01  0.52602145E+00
```

What I want as output in a file is:

```
1.1361097 1.9677992 -0.87053581
1.1361097 1.9677992  0.87053581
```

While right now I am getting:

```
[(1.1361097, 1.9677992, -0.87053581)]
[(1.1361097, 1.9677992, 0.87053581)]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
```

So my questions are:

- How to get rid of appended empty lists -> [] ?
- How do I get rid of the brackets and parentheses?

I know these questions have been asked often and I tried to work through it, but I can't resolve it. In the out-commented parts you see what I already tried...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function returns a list of tuples:

> ```
> def function(kx,ky,ek,sz,ef,tol):
>     lines = []
>     if ((ef-tol)<ek<(ef+tol)):
>         lines.append(  (kx,ky,sz)  )   # emphasis: this appends a tuple to the list
>     return lines
> ```

with `(kx,ky,sz)` being the tuple. Just return the numbers as list of floats:

```
def function(kx,ky,ek,sz,ef,tol):
    if ((ef-tol)<ek<(ef+tol)):
        return [kx,ky,sz]
    # implicitly return None if your condition is not met
```

If you want to print them not as list but as single values, decompose the list returned by `function(...)` before printing:

```
# error when decomposing None - you would have to return [] instead of None implicitly
print(* function(arr[-1][0],arr[-1][1],arr[-1][2],arr[-1][3],-0.5462,0.001), file = log)
```

You will get newlinies/errors by that though, so maybe its better to split the part writing to your other filelike this:

```
   newVals = function(arr[-1][0],arr[-1][1],arr[-1][2],arr[-1][3],-0.5462,0.001)
   if newVals: # meaning: if the function returns something, print its elements
       print(*newVals, file = log)
```

---

Nice read on [how to debug small programs (#2)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) - can be found in that link - python is very "print-out-friendly", sometimes you just have to keep some more variables around to print them and to see how the results are constructed.

Comment: Thanks for the help. It worked for me. -> on another note; I did invest way more than 15 mins to learn how to debug a snippet in my scientific life; however sometimes you fail because of lacking knowledge on a certain language - as in my case python. I am willing to learn. However waving the index finger is not encouraging...

Comment: @Nikolaij I have no idea if you are a 11y old stumbling into python , a 22y old c++ crack trying out something new or a 75y old  who invented C in the olden days. Glad I was able to help and if the article does not give you any new information all the better - I reformulated the last sentence so if might be less index waving and more a resource for someone finding this in the future.

Comment: My state of mind should be in between the persons you described. I apologise if I felt misjudged by your last sentence. I only thought that posting the code, showing what one has tried and clearly formulating questions is the right way to go here..